# how much would you be willing to pay for this card game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

suppose there are 12 cards with number 1 - 12 on each card. All cards are faced down and are listed one by one in front you.

You get to pick one card, if the card has 1 on it, you get $1.

If it's 2, you get $2, so on and so forth. Now you have the chance to put the first card back, re-shuffle it, and re-pick another card. If the second card is higher than the first card, you will get paid by an amount equivalent to the number of the second card. if the second card is less, you will get paid by whatever amount printed on the first card. How much would you be willing to pay for this game?

Comment: Just so I understand this: There is never a downside to re-pick a card, right? Can't you just say you draw two cars and get the higher one?

Comment: Not quite as you are putting the first card back, so you could draw the same card twice.

Comment: The phrasing is odd.  There is no "option" here in that there is never a reason not to draw the second card (even if you got the largest card on the first try, taking the second can't hurt).  You are just choosing two values with replacement and selecting the maximum.

Comment: The usual way to approach such "maximum" problems is to compute the probability that your two draws both have a value $≤k$ for each $k$.  Then  you get the probability that the max is exactly $k$ by subtracion.

Comment: For what it is worth, with $n$ rather than $12$ cards, the expected return would be $\frac{(n+1)(4n-1)}{6n} = \frac23n + \frac12 -\frac1{6n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $k\in \{1,\cdots, 12\}$ let $\psi(k)$ denote the probability that both of your choices are $≤k$.  Since the draws are independent we have $$\psi(k)=\left(\frac k{12}\right)^2$$

Now let $P(k)$ denote the probability that the maximum of the two draws is exactly $k$.  Clearly we have $$P(1)=\psi(1)\quad \& \quad  P(k)=\psi(k)-\psi(k-1)\quad \text {for}\,k>1$$

It is now easy to compute the expect value of the max, $$E=\sum kP(k)=8.486$$

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I just made a $12\times12$ array to represent the payouts for every possible pair of (1st draw, 2nd draw). The payout being the max of the two draws.

The average of the values in the table is the expected payout of the game. It is approximately $8.49$. "How much would you be willing to pay?" is a bit of a subjective question, but if I was running a casino with this game, I would certainly charge more than that for people to play it.